# Name of paper for encoding/representing XY coordinates in deep learning

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, computer-vision, papers

It this podcast between Oriol Vinyals and Lex Friedman: https://youtu.be/Kedt2or9xlo?t=1769, at 29:29, Oriol Vinyals refers to a paper:

> If you look at research in computer vision where it makes a lot of sense to treat images as two dimensional arrays...
>   There is actually a very nice paper from Facebook. I forgot who the
>   authors are but I think [it's] part of Kaiming He's group. And what
>   they do is they take an image, which is a 2D signal, and they
>   actually take pixel by pixel, and scramble the image, as if it
>   was a just a list of pixels, crucially they encode the position of the pixels
>   with the XY coordinates. And this is a new architecture which we
>   incidentally also use in Starcraft 2 called the transformer, which is
>   a very popular paper from last year which yielded very nice results in
>   machine translation.

Do you know which paper he is referring to?

I'm guessing maybe he is talking about [non-local neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07971), but I'm probably guessing wrong.

*Edit: after reviewing the recent publications of Kaiming He (http://kaiminghe.com/), maybe I'm guessing right. Any thoughts?*

Comment: If you verify please do update. I’d like to read that, too. Also, does this podcast have show notes? Sometimes they include links to referenced papers / blogs, etc.

Comment: This isnt the paper but it sounds related. "[An intriguing failing of convolutional neural networks and the CoordConv solution][1]" from Uber AI Labs.

They also have a [really informative video][2] and a [repo][3].


  [1]: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03247.pdf
  [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yFQc6elePA
  [3]: https://github.com/uber-research/CoordConv

Answer (score 2):

So this paper is by google, but is very similar where they use 2D positional embeddings and perform MHA on the flattened image. Are you talking about [Attention Augmented Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09925.pdf)

Comment: Looks like this is not "the" paper, but it's a good find, thanks